# Have a requirement to pass NSNumber (12.00) to NSMutable dictionary in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Have a requirement to pass NSNumber as format(12.00) to NSMutable dictionary in objective C.
Here, I have the requirement to send float as: **XX.XX format**

For an instance, [NSNumber numberfromString:@"12.34"]; **// output: 12.34 then it was fine.**

But, Had an issue with [NSNumber numberfromString:@"12.00"]; **// output: 12**

But need the output 12.00 as an NSNumber

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataProperties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] 
init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
NSNumber *value = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"12.00"];
[dataProperties setValue:value forKey:key];
```

Comment: Can you show how you "pass NSNumber ... to JSON dictionary"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Edited and added code. Please refer.
As per my API requirement, we should send xx.xx format and it should be NSnumber.

Now, the problem with 12.00

Comment: I still don't see anything about any `JSON dictionary`.

Comment: [dataProperties setValue:value forKey:key];
Here, dataProperties is an NSMutableDictionary

Comment: And this API requires that you send JSON?  How do you make *that*?  (`dataProperties` is a dictionary; it is *not* JSON, though its contents can be represented *using* JSON.)

Comment: No, we only send it as prepared NSmutableDictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245075/discussion-between-scott-hunter-and-narendra-g).

Comment: Asking that a number in JSON be shown with a fixed number of decimal places (including trailing zeros) doesn’t make sense in the Objective-C (or Swift) world. The number of fractional digits is a property of the string representation of a number, not of the number itself. So, if they’re really insisting that (a) it is a number, not a string in quotes, and that (b) they want to see the trailing zeros (e.g. `12.00`), then the answer is that this simply isn't how it works in Objective-C or Swift. Trailing zero decimal places are always removed from JSON.

Comment: But if they’re saying that they need the value rounded to two decimal places (e.g. 1.0/3.0 rounded to two decimal places is 0.33), then “rounding” is a completely legitimate request (but is not the question that was asked here). Or if they're saying that the numbers need decimal place accuracy (e.g., using `NSDecimalNumber`), then that, too, is a legitimate question.

Comment: Discussed with team and it was resolved by changing format validation.  Thanks, @ScottHunter, and Rob

Answer (score 3):

NSNumber doesn't have a format; it just has a value. And 12.00 = 12. So unless you have some other indication that this is wrong (i.e. you have tested using this API and it complained), I don't think you have a problem.